# jQuery UI Position Plugin doesn't work in lastest FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

All,

EDIT:

My example is incorrectly coded,- since I cannot delete this question I will answer. Disregard this question please.

The jQuery UI plugin for positioning element doesn't work in FireFox but works in IE and Chrome. Specifically, the plugin doesn't work when you position a div w/ respects to the mouse position (of : event). Positioning of the window or another element works.

Here's the code to try in your latest version of Fire Fox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
       $( "#div2" ).hide();
       $( "#div1" ).click(function(){


            $( "#div2" ).show().position({
                       my: "left top",
                       at: "right bottom",
                       of: event,
                       collision: "fit",

                         using: function(pos) {$(this).animate(pos);}

                    });


        });

     });
  </script>


 <div id="div1" 
    style="border: 1px solid #000; position: absolute; top: 800px; left: 1200px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: gray;" >
  </div>
  <div id="div2"
    style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: Blue;">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example is incorrectly coded,- since I cannot delete this question I will answer. Disregard this question please.

The code should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {



       $( "#div2" ).hide();
       $( "#div1" ).click(function(event){

             // Position the dialog offscreen to the left, but centered vertically
            $( "#div2" ).show().position({
                       my: "left top",
                       at: "right bottom",
                       of: event,
                       collision: "fit",

                         using: function(pos) {$(this).animate(pos);}

                    });


        });

     });
  </script>
```